# Sinatra settings returning strange result

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

I have a very simple Sinatra application:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  settings.inspect
end
```

And when I go to the root path I get: `Sinatra::Application` which is not at all what I expected. The application also doesn't respond well when I call the `development?` method (`NoMethodError`). I get the feeling this is because of my environment. I'm running Sinatra 1.4.4 with Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 8. Any ideas on how to figure this out?

Comment: Are you calling just `development?` or `settings.development?`? (It should be the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right, it’s just the way Sinatra works.

The [`settings` instance method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L909-911) calls the class method (with `self.class.settings`) and the [class method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L904-906) simply returns `self`, which is `Sinatra::Application` in the case of classic apps, and whatever your app class is in the case of modular apps.

When you add a setting in Sinatra with `set`, a new [method is created on the app class for it](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1217-1219), rather than there being a separate settings object. There is no way, as far as I know, to iterate over just the settings of your app.